# jQuery fadeToggle makes row background color disappear

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, fade

This is a **Firefox** only problem. This works fine on Chrome and Internet Explorer.

If you have a `background-color` on a table row, then hide the row using `fadeToggle` and then show it again, the background-color for the padding goes back to the default.

I have it trapped down to this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/icc97/2EYxC/), that just has one link doing a `fadeToggle` of a single row.

#### Before toggle

[image: Before toggle]

#### After toggle

[image: After toggle - missing padding colour]

#### HTML

```
<a href="#" id="toggle">Toggle</a>
<table class="">
    <tr class="cat1">
        <td>data1</td><td>data2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### CSS

```
body {background-color: #ccc}
table {border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #fff}
td {border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;}
tr.cat1 {background-color: #ddd;}
```

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toggle').click(function () { 
        $('tr.cat1').fadeToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

Things I've figured out:

- If you switch tab and then switch back then the background-color fixes itself
- If you remove `border-collapse: collapse` then the problem goes away
- jQuery `hide` then `show` works fine

**So is it possible to get `fadeToggle` to work correctly in Firefox?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This 1 will work for u:- [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2EYxC/6/)

```
$('#toggle').click(function () {
      $('tr.cat1 td').fadeToggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Any chance you'd know why it then fails when including the Twitter Bootstrap styles? I know then it gets more complicated e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/icc97/2EYxC/10/. You'll see there that after applying your fix, it still leaves has the problem